# How do i get output JsBarcode ITF-14 format

Tags: javascript, barcode-printing, jsbarcode

I am using JsBarcode library in my project. I use CODE128 format as standard but now I want to use ITF-14. It works but no framework is added. Is there any solution about it ?

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/barcodes/JsBarcode.itf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      JsBarcode(".barcode", "1012312312312", {
        format: "ITF14",
      });
    });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-value="CAN" jsbarcode-width="2" jsbarcode-height="60" jsbarcode-marginTop="10"
      margin="5">
    </svg>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

WHAT I WANT

[image]

Comment: Check this http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-itf-14.html

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but using it as xml doesn't give me solution :(